# Is there an aptitude equivalent to yum/dnf groups?

Tags: package-management

```
dnf groupinstall "Development and Creative Workstation"
dnf groupinfo "Compute Node"
```

Comment: What aspect of the groups are you looking for? Do https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MetaPackages do what you want?

Comment: Meta packages are closest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There’s no direct equivalent to yum/dnf groups in Debian derivatives, at least not from a user’s or administrator’s perspective.

The technical equivalents are [tasks](https://wiki.debian.org/tasksel) and [metapackages](https://wiki.debian.org/metapackage), technical in the sense that they could be used to provide the same functionality as groups. However, tasks are used mostly for system installation (in particular, choosing the appropriate packages for a given desktop environment in a given locale, and setting up one of a few server scenarios), and metapackages are used for a variety of purposes (see [the list of Debian metapackages](https://packages.debian.org/stable/metapackages/)). Some metapackages correspond to a yum/dnf group, but there’s no guarantee you’ll find an equivalent for all the groups you might be interested in.

As far as I’m aware, there’s no one in Debian or Ubuntu working on providing functional sets of packages with purposes similar to yum/dnf groups.